# Check the database for a postmeta field

Tags: php, posts, wp-query

So I'm trying to use the metadata exists call to check the WordPress database and see if some metadata exists.

For some reason, I don't think if the `metadata_exists` call is the correct one in this case, but I would like to check the database and see if an metadata of `_octopus_id` exists.

Comment: Seems like `metadata_exists()` would be fine for this use case. Note that the second parameter for `metadata_exists( string $meta_type, int $object_id, string $meta_key )` is an `int` for the object to check. You're passing in the whole `WP_Query` object, which is not correct. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/metadata_exists/

Comment: Thanks @DaveRomsey, let me look into it some more so that I can understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to set a new WP_Query since you are looping through the data of the octopus. I would do the following in your case:

Create a function that checks if there is a post with an octopus_id given

```
function post_with_octopus_id_exists( $octopus_id ){

    //If for some reason the $octopus_id given is empty return false
    if( empty( $octopus_id ) ){
        return false;
    }

    //Do a meta query to fetch posts with the given $octopus_id
    $args = array(
       'post_type'      => 'employee',
       'post_status'    => 'any'
       'meta_query'     => array(
            'relation'  => AND,
            array(
                'key'       => '_octopus_id',
                'compare'   => 'EXISTS'
            ),
            array(
               'key'        => '_octopus_id',
               'value'      => $octopus_id,
               'compare'    => '=',
           )
       )
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

    //if there are posts with the given $octopus_id return true otherwise return false
    return ( $the_query->have_posts() ? true : false ); 

}
```

Then inside your loop you can call the function as following:

```
foreach ( $records->data as $record ) {

    if( ! post_with_octopus_id_exists( $record->id ) ){
        echo "Hello";
    }

}
```

**Important:** Make sure that the meta_key stored for each post is named as "_octopus_id"

Comment: This has been amazing help @giannisrig! Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem, I am glad it helped you!